# SQL - Trim and only leave the last word left in a string when convert and replace already use

Tags: sql

This is my Output : `=//Resources/Users/233d4f24-010a-4b22-b7d6-384a101b2f3c;John Smith.`

How do I trim it so that it only displays John Smith.
Thanks so much.

This is my code.

```
Select
convert(xml,replace(convert(nvarchar(max), jq.Arguments), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16')).value('arguments[1]/services[1]/instance[1]/data[1]/owner1[1]','varchar(100)') as 'Owner2',
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If semicolon will always be your separator, and there will only ever be the one semicolon, you can use Char Index to find where the semicolon is in your string, use length and subtract that from the full length of the string for how many characters you want, then grab all characters after it with a right trim:

```
right(YourColumn,len(YourColumn)-CHARINDEX('-',YourColumn))
```

If the above code is what you used to get your column, replace all instances of YourColumn in the above statement with your code:

```
right(convert(xml,replace(convert(nvarchar(max), jq.Arguments), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16')).value('arguments[1]/services[1]/instance[1]/data[1]/owner1[1]','varchar(100)'),
len(convert(xml,replace(convert(nvarchar(max), jq.Arguments), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16')).value('arguments[1]/services[1]/instance[1]/data[1]/owner1[1]','varchar(100)'))
-CHARINDEX('-',convert(xml,replace(convert(nvarchar(max), jq.Arguments), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16')).value('arguments[1]/services[1]/instance[1]/data[1]/owner1[1]','varchar(100)'))) as Owner3,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  If you want to get rid of everything up to the semicolon:

```
select stuff(jq.Arguments, 1, charindex(';', jq.Arguments) + 1, '')
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon . The problem is that within the arguments there are lots of data and I only want the data/'Owner' and not anything else?

Comment: @MichelleNZ . . . The point is that this takes everything after the semicolon.  That appears to be what the question is asking for.